# Scale images of UIImage in UIStackView to fit screen size in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, crop, uistackview

On my iOS app written in Swift 3, I have 4 UIImages, each 2 in a UIStackView, and the 2 UIStackViews inside another UIStackView, as shown in the picture below:

[image]

In the picture you can see the division I made to the images.

You can also see the problem, when the images are exiting the screen and the user can't see the full image because it's get cropped.

All images are on "2x" size on their Image Set in `Assets.xcassets`.

On `Main.storyboard` on the Attributes Inspector I changed the Content Mode to "Scale To Fill" for all 4 images. I also did that in code:

```
phoneCallImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
sendEmailImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
sendSmsImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
openFacebookImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
```

I also tried to do that with the full UIStackView (Images Stack View in the picture):

```
imagesStackView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
```

What can I do to fix this and show the full image without cropping it?

Comment: I think you haven't added all the constraints.. the outer stackview should fit inside the view. click on the errors in constraints and you might get an idea whats happening..

Comment: I think setting a leading and trailing constraint for the outer stackview can fix your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set up constraints for the individual images and the containing stack views.

<del>For each image you will need to specify a width constraint equal to the top most stack view with a multiplier of 0.5 (50% of parent width) so that it scales with the screen size.</del>

Then for each image you may want to use a constraint for the aspect ratio to keep it 1:1 so that the height scales equally as well.

Then for the top stack view you'll want to constrain its width to the parent view as well and then add constraints for left margin and y position.

See images for the constraints and the final result.

[image: You dont need the width constraints]
[image: The end result]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this.
First I selected the full UIStackView (Images Stack View in the picture) and added constraints to it, to set the margins to 0:

[image]

After that I chose everyone of the images in the UIStackView and changed its width and height to 171.5 from the constraints menu, in order it to be a square:

[image]

After that, everything was perfectly aligned into the screen.